# SQL Query for Random 10% with a minimum of 20 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I have been tasked with generating a report that will randomly pick 10% of a unique ID, unless 10% is less than 20 items in which case the report would pick 20 random ID's.
I have been using `NewID` to generate the 10%, but that really isn't the best as it gives me variable results (IE: more or less than 10%)

Code also includes my attempts to get a total count of the results:

```
select  UniqueID, TotalCount = Count(*) Over(), SUM(COUNT(UniqueID)) OVER() 
AS total_count 
from table 
where 0.15 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), UniqueID) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int)
group by UniqueID
```

Comment: Can you word this a bit clearer? Are you saying you want a report that will return 10% of the entire dataset given it is more than 20 rows? If less than 20 just give everything?

Comment: I don't understand.  What unique id do you want it to pick?  Why do you only choose 20 when you have 200 of them?

Comment: I think they should only return 20 when 10% of the result set would be < 20. So if 10% was 316, it should return 316 @GordonLinoff

Comment: Yes @gordonLinoff, it should return 20 when 10% of the results would be < 20. Thanks for the quick replies. I will test them out now.

Answer (score 1):

I would generate a row_number ordered on new_id, then work out how many (N) of the rows you can take (rows 1......N) have to be random.  if you have less than 20 rows, you get all rows

whatever your query needs to be, put it in the 
WITH CTE AS ("your query here")

and add the row_number() over (order by newid()) as x to the list of selected columns

```
WITH CTE AS
  (select *,row_number() over (order by newid()) as x from istasks ) 
  SELECT * 
  FROM CTE 
  CROSS APPLY 
       (SELECT MAX(c2.X) MX, ROUND(.1* MAX(c2.X),0) P  --P is no rows needed according to 10% rule  
        FROM CTE C2
       ) DQ
  WHERE CTE.X <= CASE WHEN P < 20 THEN 20 ELSE P END  --take 20 rows if P < 20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((select count (*) as a from (select top 10 percent * from  [table]) t) < 20)
BEGIN
Select top 20 * from [table] order by newid()
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN
select top 10 percent * from  [table] order by newid() END
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how the code answers the question improves its long-term value. It also helps avoid having your answer down-voted or flagged as low quality. See [How to Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know the total amount of rows, then the construct below is probably the fastest approach for your "10% or first 20" requirement

```
If (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
      SELECT TOP 200 *  -- if 10% = 20, then 100% = 200
      FROM [table]       ) AS top200
   ) < 200
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 20 ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT ...
END
```

Note that there is no ORDER BY in the inner query

Answer (score 0):

If there was a `UniqueID` in your table where `COUNT(UniqueID)` was greater than 1 (per `UniqueID`), then that *UniqueID* wasn’t *unique*, so the `TotalCount` and `total_count` columns in your query should return the same values.

To filter out the top 10 percent (or at least 20) of your records, you could calculate a random row number (using `NEWID()`) and apply a filter to it (including the total number of records). Both the row number and the total number of records can be calculated using *window functions* (with an OVER clause), but since these functions can’t be used in a WHERE clause (they provide additional information after the regular result set has been generated), the calculation must happen in a subquery (which can be written as a CTE). My suggestion is to try it like this:

```
WITH
  cte AS (
    SELECT UniqueID,
      RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()),
      MaxNumber = COUNT(*) OVER ()
    FROM YourTable
  )
SELECT UniqueID
FROM cte
WHERE RowNumber <= MaxNumber/10 OR RowNumber <= 20;
```

If you need to *round* the 10% value up for fractional values (like TOP x PERCENT does), try an alternative WHERE clause:

```
WHERE RowNumber <= (MaxNumber+9)/10 OR RowNumber <= 20;
```